# Read a text (txt) file with image values into a Vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am reading a txt file containing image values into a 2D vector. However when the code finishes reading the file and when I check the size of the vector it is not equal in dimensions to the size of the vector i expect (5568 rows by 5877 columns). Kindly advice me where I am going wrong, I am still a learner in C++. Below is my code:

```
enum ERROR{
    FAILED_TO_OPEN_FILE = 1,
    FILE_IS_NOT_OPEN    = 2
};

//load training vector
std::ifstream trainingset;
trainingset.open("E:\\DATA\\WorkDIR\\Fuhrberg\\2009\\Input\\try.txt");
 if (!trainingset) {
     cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
     return FAILED_TO_OPEN_FILE;
 }
const int gRows = 5568, gCols = 5877;
vector <vector<int>> traindata(gRows, vector<int >( gCols ) );
if(!trainingset.is_open()) return FILE_IS_NOT_OPEN;
for (int iii = 0; iii < gRows; iii++){
    vector<int> row;
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < gCols; jjj++){
        int readFromFile = 0;
        trainingset >> readFromFile;
        row.push_back(readFromFile);
        //cout << row[jjj] << "\t"
    }
    traindata[iii] = row;
    //cout << endl;
}
trainingset.close();
cout << "vector size \t" << traindata.size() <<endl;
```

Comment: What size does it report?

Comment: I have changed the code as edited above, but still get the size of the vector as 5568 instead of 5568 rows by 5877 columns, anything more I should do?

Comment: `traindata` has 5568 *vectors* with 5877 int's each one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Just change:

```
vector <vector<int>> traindata(gRows, vector<int >( gCols ) );
```

With:

```
vector <vector<int>> traindata;
```

In the first way, you're creating your `vector` with `gRows` elements (*the default ones*) and then you use `push_back()`, so you're inserting more elements at the end.

---

Also, I suggest you to reserve `grows`, so, your code will be like this:

```
vector <vector<int>> traindata;
traindata.reserve(grows);
```

---

#### Solution 2

Another possibility is to let the definition of `traindata` as it, but then not to use `push_back()`, using the `operator[]` and `=` instead.

In this way you must change:

```
traindata.push_back(row);
```

With:

```
traindata[iii] = row;
```

Comment: I have changed the code as edited above, but still get the size of the vector as 5568 instead of 5568 rows by 5877 columns, anything more I should do?

Comment: Now you've corrected the code, the result is as expected: `traindata.size()` is 5568 (`grows`).

Comment: So how can I get a vector of 5568 rows by 5877 columns? Any more advice?

Comment: That's the right way but you're just printing the number of rows. Just add the following to your code to print the number of columns: `cout << "columns \t" << traindata.front().size() <<endl;`